# Comments should be more evident in profiles

Tags: feature-request, comments, profile-page

In the profile area of the site, there is a section for each important type of action taken by the given user.

Written comments, however are listed only in the *All Actions* section, and to see them separately you need to use the filter (I assume this makes them quite difficult for new users to find).

My question is: why not dedicate a section in the profile to show only written comments, with the possibility to sort them by creation date and votes, like there is for questions and answers?

I don't want to argue about the classification and importance of comments, that's a philosophical problem and is separate.

Since comments can be voted, deleted and for certain periods edited, I think the possibility to view them grouped and ordered would be useful. In the profile in addition to questions and answers are also listed: Tags, Badges, Bookmarks, Following, Replies and Votes. I think comments are more interesting than some of the other types of information since they involve more interactions. Comments often contain key information even if they are short, so I think for summarizing a profile they should be shown.

My proposal is just to move comments to a new section, I don't think this will change their status (after all, comments are already in the profile). The interface needs to be functional; it doesn't need to adhere to dogma. End users are not interested in these philosophical issues but in the functionality of the site, and I don't think giving comments a separate section would confuse users. Right now is difficult to find them and I'm not asking to display obscure information that is about only moderators, I think that also other people want to view them since some users write a lot of comments, so it is interesting info to show.

Comment: I'd have to agree on this one... I feel like I'm heading into my comments tab several times a day to find the most recent posts I've requested clarification on, and that section can take a while to load if you're super active or have a very old account with a lot of actions. It being on the summary page, even if only the last 5, would be helpful.

Comment: wonder if you checked [meta-tag:comments] tag description, "...Comments are second-class citizens"

Comment: I *assume* that the official reasoning for why comments aren't displayed more prominently on the profile is because they're ["sticky notes"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment)/ second-class citizens to questions and answers (which are the real stores of content across Stack). There is a never-ending, ongoing war about what that _actually means_ in practice, and it varies between Stack sites, but it's still a reality here and across the network.

Comment: Frankly, folks, I too find myself in agreement with the OP here. Second-class citizens the comments may be (which I 100% agree with), when engaging in a moderately active day with discussions across the network I find myself having to go to the tab to even wrap my head about what was written. Sometimes all I remember about something important now is that I made a comment a while back (yes, SEDE can be used but we can't expect everyone to be a tsql wizard). In both of these situations reducing the number of clicks needed to reach them is a more efficient and less frustrating UX.

Comment: But fret not as the UI team lead is in no way interested in improving the quality of life for active users of the network - so we can perpetually discuss the benefits and drawbacks of changing the UI without any risk of change...

Comment: Anyone can go to their own comments at: https://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=activity&sort=comments, with their comments on all SE sites [available on the main Stack Exchange site](//stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=activity) (the "comments" sub-tab; while directly linking to it is possible, it looses formatting when doing so). If people are really looking at other user's comments all that often then it might be reasonable to pull these onto the profile summary tab. If you're often reading your own comments, it's not clear to me why you wouldn't just use a browser bookmark.

Comment: @Makyen Sure it is possible to use a browser bookmark (good idea), but I was wondering why requiring further steps from users (even if simple) when it would be enough to include comments in the summary. I think in a site like this where users spend a lot of time even a small amount of time saved is important. Most of the actions performed by the user are shown in the profile (not only questions and answers), so for me add a comments section would be natural (also other sections are not vital). In addition, this solution is not suitable for viewing comments written by others (as you noted).

Comment: I'm fine with a bookmark/quickmark. If you prefer clicking on your profile image to view it you can write a userscript I guess

Comment: @OlegValter:  Plot twist: they'd introduce this change while refactoring the profile to make it more responsive.

Comment: @Makoto I promise to eat my hat if that happens :)

Comment: @KevinB looking at the comments list to check on updates can be partly replaced by [following](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345661/the-follow-questions-and-answers-feature-is-now-live-across-the-network) the posts that you comment on - although I often don't remember if I have indeed followed a post or not so I still check my comment list regularly.

Comment: honestly didn't even know you could see comments in a profile at all, they're so well hidden

Comment: @AryanBeezadhur I had the impression that "edit" were to be avoided, since it doesn't fit with the wikipedia style that Stack wants to be. You seem to have made it screaming..

Comment: @Scratte Stack Overflow aims to be a  Q&A site and a knowledge base, not a Wikipedia for programming. On Stack Overflow, emphasising "Edit" headers is important because the OP is making an important comment for the record, or else it would just be edited and "blended in" to the existing post. This happens because of Stack Overflow's Q&A format, as opposed to Wikipedia's article format. Therefore, the "Edit" should be emphasised. I've made it an `h2` instead of `h1` to reduce aggressiveness, but I think it still deserves importance.

Comment: @gnat "...Comments are second-class citizens" But this only means that I'm okay with them being deleted if needed. It doesn't mean I don't use them at all. I comment orders of magnitude more often than asking or answering. And I also need to search within them more often than in my questions or answers. It would save me time if they were one click less away. But this would be a much too pragmatic approach.

Comment: Personally I think there are bigger things this site needs to work on

Comment: @AryanBeezadhur re: "edit header", [that's not what the community has agreed though.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/127639/241919)

Comment: @AndrewT. from [the accepted answer on the post you linked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/127655/380081), "edit/update" headers are acceptable if the OP is adding some important information *after users have commented or answered*, which clarifies the question or point of view, and is important enough so that it should not get buried in the comments. Therefore, the header is acceptable for this question IMO.

Comment: "I don't want to argue about the classification and importance of comments, that's a philosophical problem and is separate." You say that. Yet, you follow it up with an argument for why comments are "more interesting". And ultimately that's fair, as the relative importance of comments is really at the heart of this question, since it's about elevating their relative placement on the profile. But let's be clear about that, instead of trying to sidestep the underlying question or pretending it's not relevant to the suggestion.

Comment: @JeremyCaney My intention was not to dispute that comments are second-class citizens, because that is a taxonomic-philosophical problem that I don' t care. I'm not disputing the importance of comments over questions/answers, I simply pointed out that they can contain interesting info to show (many comments do not contain only small details). I'm surprised at how much uproar this question has caused, since it's a simple proposal to move comments to another profile area like other infos as a matter of usability, which I think interests the average user more than these meticulous clarifications

Comment: @JeremyCaney I said the comments were interesting to explain why I wanted to move them (how else could I have argued?), but I pointed out that I wasn't debating their importance because I don't want to change their dictionary definition. Giving them their own tab doesn't mean promoting them to first-class citizens, since almost all the information already has its own tab. Honestly when I wrote my question I wasn't even aware of this controversy, so my proposal was purely about the UI and not about the importance or unimportance of comments

Answer (score 17):

## Comments are not more important than questions or answers.

- You can't search comments.
- You can't edit comments after a period of time.
- You gain no reputation from comments.
- Comments can be deleted at any time, for any reason.

Only moderators would need to have that kind of ready access to a user's comment history, and even then I would presume they have a better way to get at it.

Also too, if I *really* wanted to get your comments, [there's already a link for that](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16732898/redwheelbarrow?tab=activity&sort=comments).

Comment: My answer is unchanged @RedWheelbarrow.  Making them more prominent in the profile when they *aren't* by definition is a design flaw.

Comment: I don't agree, but I see your point.

Comment: _"You can't search comments"_ This is a major drawback. I do agree with your answer though.

Comment: As an aside, SEDE exposes comments, though you obviously only get comments which are older than the previous Sunday (which is how often SEDE gets updated from the main site). Example: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1450901/search-my-comments

Comment: I don't think anyone's claimed that comments are **more** important than questions or answers. I also don't really agree with the asker's opinion that they are **as** important as questions and answers. But that doesn't mean they're not useful, especially recent ones you've made trying to get clarification that you might want to check back on. It would be able to just check, say, your own last ten comments, without quite so many clicks.

Comment: @CrazyChucky: Just from a UX perspective, by placing something inconsequential in a high visibility spot, one immediately gets the perception that it is more valuable than it should be. There's already a way to get comments in your profile. It is not the primary thing that people use, so there's little reason to make it more prominent.

Answer (score 4):

I think comments are way more important than Meta usually dares to admit. "Second-class citizens" is a phrase repeated often, but not necessarily holding a particular value, other than being a catchphrase.

Ask an unclear question? You get comments. Misinterpret a question and post a wrong answer? Comment. Question got closed incorrectly? Comment, right away. An answer is outdated or the code therein is not copy-pastable? Believe it or not, comment, right away.

Comments help shape the community by determining what's okay and what isn't, by educating (potential) askers and answerers alike. They're disregarded too easily on Meta sometimes.

Just their sheer number and their upvotes prove that many members hold them in higher regard that is usually voiced here. They can be deleted automatically by enough flags or manually by a moderator, but they do hold value, for askers, answerers, voters and later visitors.

Now as for your question: I do not necessarily see the need to make comments more prominent in the profile, especially not for other users. If you want to follow what a certain user posts, you can visit the "comments" subtab on their "all actions" tab.

When *I* comment (which my profile proves I do more than I write answers), it's usually accompanied by a vote on the post, either up or down or close. That way I can track my way back to my comments through the "votes" tab.

Did I closevote and I or someone else commented? Then chances are I'll revisit the post after a few hours or days to see if something improved.

So if you want to give comments a more prominent place on the profile, please explain your use case and how exactly that would help.

Comment: Acknowledging that voting can be a bit capricious on Meta, I’m a bit surprised that this answer is apparently controversial—unless people are voting immediately after finishing the first paragraph, and assuming they know what the rest will say. This all seems pretty sensible to me. Aside, I appreciate your diligence in going back and monitoring your votes for updates.